# View.Title == ViewData["Title"]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

am confused right now with Razor ViewEngine for ASP.NET MVC.

most of you would say:

```
View.Title
```

is the same with

```
ViewData["Title"]
```

after running the application I get this

> Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The
>   name 'View' does not exist in the
>   current context

what gives? did I miss something?
am using VWD 2010 Express + ASP.NET MVC 3 R2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's been changed to ViewBag in the latest RC.

```
ViewBag.Title = "Test";
```

See [ScottGu's post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/10/announcing-asp-net-mvc-3-release-candidate-2.aspx) on breaking changes in the latest MVC 3 release candidate.

Comment: Click the checkbox outline next to my answer. Make sure you do this whenever anyone provides you the correct answer to one of your questions. Look at the FAQs by clicking the link at the very top of the page.